# Is it possible to use an AWS SSL/TLS cert on Route 53 for a server/domain on another host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

A friend of mine wanted me to set up Route 53 for his DNS for some reason, which is to be used for business purposes. His website is hosted through Godaddy.com and his domain is also purchased through that service. So I set up Route 53 and Godaddy such that when his domain is navigated to in a browser, the AWS nameservers are used and Route 53 resolves the domain to the Godaddy IP.

I've never used another DNS service before, but now I need to add SSL support. What's the best way to do this? AWS offers a SSL cert for free, but I have a suspicion that this may need to be done on the hosting provider server.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. AWS offers free certificates, which needs to be used along with other AWS resources like load balancer. You won't be able to make use of this free certificate in your case, as your website is hosted out of AWS. In this case you would rather need to purchase a certificate (from 3rd party like GoDaddy or Digicert) and get this installed in GoDaddy server. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

One option that's a bit more cost effective than buying a certificate is to use Let's Encrypt instead, especially if you can use certbot with your current hosting, since it's completely free of charge and certbot handles the renewal of any certificates for you.